# Music that helps a baby to sleep

Tags: sleep, newborn, music

I am wondering if it is practical to play music that helps a baby to sleep.

If it is, which is your favourite?

Answer (score 3):

If it is a small baby, generally the singing of the parents is better than any other music as the baby knows this sounds well.  When mine are small, if I play anything at all it would be ocean sounds or natural sounds versus music, when it comes to sleep.  Inside the body, the sound of blood pumping in mom's body does sound a lot like like ocean noises, so I think that is often soothing to them.

I also think each child is different.  My oldest was far better soothed by more intense music rather than what an adult would call soothing.  He would be quieted in the car for instance by music that was very lively.  If I put on anything mellow (which I personally prefer when driving) he would be come more upset by it than silence.

As my children got older I started to play meditation music & sounds for them before bedtime because mediation before bed is something I practice & intended to always teach them.  So for me, it seemed to make sense for them to get used to the sounds earlier on, so that when I started to teach them the practice, it already felt like a natural extension of what they were already doing.

Just try things until you find your baby's preference.  Also keep in mind, that when a small child gets used to something, it can become something they rely on.  This is usually no issue, until something happens like a loss of power, travel, etc & then it might become an issue.  I bought a nightlight that worked well that played stars on the ceiling, had options for sounds like ocean & crickets, etc, and it could be plugged in or run on a battery.  It then becomes something you can take anywhere & will work whether the power is on or not.  The only issue was that I once forgot to pack it on a trip and I realized what a crutch it had become to my kids.  I accept that, but it is for sure something they are so used to that they find it hard to sleep without.  I also now bought about 4 more because this will sure some day quit working and until they are older, I prefer to have backup units.

Answer (score 1):

Our family discovered that playing some calming music or sounds of nature has really soothing effect on the child (honestly, adults also started to sleep better with addition of quiet and calming motives).

As for the example - Mozart used to switch off my nephew faster and better than anything. Some Vivaldi also is helpful. Sound of rain is my personal favorite.

Answer (score 0):

It absolutely depends on the child. Many children like classical music, ambient sounds or  other calming music. There is also music specially composed to make children sleep.

However, my daughter realize with a few months of age that soothing music was ment to make her sleep and she would start to fight against the sleep. Instead,  my daughter sleeps best with music like Shakira. She loves when I dance with her in my arms to fast music and usually falls asleep quickly this way without fighting. (How fast you dance depends of course on the age of the child, remember not to shake her head too much)

So it really depends on the child and every child is different.

I would recommend to have at least two ways of putting your child to sleep: If you always dance with her to make her sleep, she will get used to it and if one of you is not in the mood for music, this can get problematic. But using music and dancing as backup, if nothing else helps should be fine.